# Grouping Counting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  Date        Date_Solved      Ticket_ID  
1   01.01.2023  NULL             123    
2   01.01.2023  02.01.2023      
3   01.01.2023  02.01.2023      
4   02.01.2023  NULL             456    
5   02.01.2023  NULL        
…   …   …   …
```

And would like to groupby/count it into this format:

```
Date        Sum Sum_Open Sum_Solved Sum_Ticket
01.01.2023  3   3        Null       1
02.01.2023  2   3        2          2
```

In the original dataframe ID is a unique value for a ticket.

Sum: Each day tickets can be opened. This is the sum per day.

```
df = df_subset.groupby(['Date'])['Date'].count()
```

Sum_Open: Tickets can be solved on the same day or later. Sum_Open Is the sum of all entrys having a solved date >Date or no Solved Date at all

Sum_Solved: Is the sum of all entrys having a solved date = Date

Sum_Tickets is the sum of all unsolved tickets having an entry at Ticket_ID

Comment: Your application has been received. Looking forward to posting your attempted solutions.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword is cumulative sum:

```
result['Gemeldet_Gesamt'] = result['Gemeldet_Am'].cumsum()
result['Gelöst_Gesamt'] = result['Gelöst_Am'].cumsum()
result['Netto'] = result['Gemeldet_Am'] - result['Gelöst_Am']
result['Netto_Gesamt'] = result['Netto'].cumsum()
```